# join strings in a list when indexes are unknown

Tags: python, string

so I'm still relatively new to python and I am having some trouble with my data structures.  Specifically what I am trying to do here is join strings in a list.  My code looks like this.
import re

```
FstFile = open('q1/fst1', 'ru')
InputFile = open('examples/ex', 'ru')

def cleanseInput(strVal):
    return re.sub(r'\"', '', re.sub(r'\'', '', strVal))

fstLines =FstFile.readlines()
#print fstLines 

FstStore = []
for item in fstLines:
   x = item.strip().split('\n')
   FstStore.append(x[0])

AcceptState = FstStore.pop(0)

#print FstStore
#print AcceptState
transitionStates = []
for item in FstStore:
    item = item[1: -1]
    #print item
    transitionStates.append(item[0])
    item = item[3: -1]
    #transitionStates.append(item[0])
    x = cleanseInput(item)
    #print x
    for i in x:
        transitionStates.append(i)
    #print i
#print transitionStates    
new = []
for k in transitionStates:
    #print k
    if(k != (r' ')):
        new.append(k)
for k in range(0, len(transitionStates)):
    #print transitionStates[k]
    if transitionStates[k] == '*':
        #print transitionStates[k]

print new
```

The output I'm getting looks like this:
['0', '1', 'a', '!', 'e', '!', '1', '0', 'a', 'b']

What I would like to do is join the '!' 'e' '!' into a single element '!e!' I'm having trouble with this because the location of these symbols in the list may vary depending on the file so I can't directly splice the string.
Any suggestions?

Comment: We need some more details on the actual specification for your tokenizing. Does order matter? I.E. would `['!',...,'!',...,'e']` also be turned into `'!e!'`? Are the elements always unique, I.E. is it safe to assume there would only ever be either zero or two `'!'` and one `'e'`? etc. etc. The answer to this question depends *greatly* on what the rules for your grammar are.

Comment: So for this specific assignment the ! will only appear in the sequence !e!.  SO order does matter however, there won't be other occurrences of ! outside of the !e! string

Answer (score 0):

here is one (probably suboptimal) solution

```
initial_string = "".join(['0', '1', 'a', '!', 'e', '!', '1', '0', 'a', 'b'])
import re
def StateMachineValidation(s,pat):
    return re.match(pat,s)

def Matcher(s,pat):
    match_len = len(pat)
    while s:
        if StateMachineValidation(s,pat):
           yield "".join(s[:match_len])
           s = s[match_len:]
        else:
           yield s[0]
           s = s[1:]

print list(Matcher(initial_string,"!.!"))
```

Comment: Hmm I tried implementing this solution however when I attempt to execute, I get a nothing to repeat error.  I can't seem to figure out why...

Comment: nothing in this code will cause that  ... you would need to provide an example that breaks for me to tell you why... Im not even sure what you mean by "nothing to repeat error"

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the issue and this works great for me.  Thanks for your help!